# How to add link (which is clickable column by column and fetch data) from google column chart api

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

Recently I have used Google Chart API to draw a column chart from the data I retrieve from mySQL.

I want to add external link in google chart for each column chart of it to get the aging days of datediff(current_timestamp,inserted_time from database) between how many days as the image provided.

[image: screenshot 1]
Aging Dashboard Google Column Chart API

as well as 2nd image provided
[image: screenshot 2]
A table of the column chart displayed after clicking of one of the column chart

Aging.js

```
 layui.use(['form', 'element', 'laydate', 'jquery', 'layer', 'table'], function() {
var $ = layui.$,
    layerTips = parent.layer === undefined ? layui.layer : parent.layer,
    form = layui.form,
    table = layui.table,
    laydate = layui.laydate;


$('.chart').hide();                                                          
form.on('submit(search)', function() {
    form.scheme = $('#scheme').val();
    form.counter = $('#counter').val();
    form.status = $('#status').val();
    form.merchant = $('#merchant').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '../../graph-data',
        dateType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(form),
        error: function() {
            console.log("error");
        },
        success: function(res) {
            
            // Google chart
            var result = [];
            if ($('#counter').val() == "cases") {
                result.push(["Days", "Cases", { role: "style" }]);

            } else {
                result.push(["Days", "Amount", { role: "style" }]);
            }
            if (res['aging2ChartResult'].length != 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < res['aging2ChartResult'].length; i++) {


                    if ($('#counter').val() == "amount") {
                        var item = ["Less than 10 day", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['amount1'], "lightgreen "]
                        var item1 = ["Between 10 ~ 19 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['amount2'], "lightgreen"]
                        var item2 = ["Between 20 ~ 29 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['amount3'], "lightgreen"]
                        var item3 = ["Between 30 ~ 39 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['amount4'], "lightgreen"]
                        var item4 = ["Between 40 ~ 49 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['amount5'], "lightgreen"]
                        var item5 = ["Between 50 ~ 59 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['amount6'], "lightgreen"]
                        var item6 = ["Between 60 ~ 69 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['amount7'], "lightgreen"]
                        var item7 = ["Between 70 ~ 79 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['amount8'], "lightgreen"]
                        var item8 = ["Between 80 ~ 89 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['amount9'], "lightgreen"]
                        var item9 = ["At 90 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['amount10'], "lightgreen"]
                        var item10 = ["More than 90 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['amount11'], "lightgreen"]
                            // console.log(res);
                    } else {
                        var item = ["Less than 10 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['less10d'], "lightgreen"]
                        var item1 = ["Between 10 ~ 19 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['between10d'], "lightgreen"]
                        var item2 = ["Between 20 ~ 29 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['between20d'], "lightgreen"]
                        var item3 = ["Between 30 ~ 39 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['between30d'], "lightgreen"]
                        var item4 = ["Between 40 ~ 49 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['between40d'], "lightgreen"]
                        var item5 = ["Between 50 ~ 59 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['between50d'], "lightgreen"]
                        var item6 = ["Between 60 ~ 69 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['between60d'], "lightgreen"]
                        var item7 = ["Between 70 ~ 79 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['between70d'], "lightgreen"]
                        var item8 = ["Between 80 ~ 89 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['between80d'], "lightgreen"]
                        var item9 = ["At 90 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['equal90d'], "lightgreen"]
                        var item10 = ["More than 90 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['moret90d'], "lightgreen"]

                    }

                    result.push(item, item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, item10);
                }
                google.charts.load("current", {
                    packages: ['corechart']
                });
                google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

                function drawChart() {
                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(result);
                    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
                    view.setColumns([0, 1, {
                            calc: "stringify",
                            sourceColumn: 1,
                            type: "string",
                            role: "annotation"
                        },
                        2
                    ]);

                    var options = {
                        title: $('#counter').val() == "amount" ? "Amount(RM)" : "Cases",
                        vAxis: {
                            title: form.unit == "amount" ? "Amount(RM)" : "Cases",
                        },
                        hAxis: {
                            title: 'Aging Days'
                        },
                        width: 1100,
                        height: 400,
                        bar: {
                            groupWidth: "75%"
                        },
                        legend: {
                            position: "none"
                        },
                    };
                    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));          
chart.draw(view, options);

}
                $('.chart').show();
            } else {
                $('.chart').hide();
            }
        },
    });
});
});
```

and below is my aging.html file

```
<head>
<title>Aging</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="layui-container chart">
<div id="columnchart_values" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my SQL(Mapper.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" 
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="xx.xx.xx.dao.ReportMapper">
 <resultMap id="AgingMerchantInfo" type="xx.xx.xx.model.dto.AgingMerchantInfo">
    <result column="branch_name" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="branchName" />
    <result column="agent_code" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="agentCode" />

</resultMap>

<resultMap id="Aging2ResultMap" type="xx.xx.xx.model.dto.Aging2ChartResultInfo">
    <result column="amount1" jdbcType="DECIMAL" property="amount1" />
    <result column="amount2" jdbcType="DECIMAL" property="amount2" />
    <result column="amount3" jdbcType="DECIMAL" property="amount3" />
    <result column="amount4" jdbcType="DECIMAL" property="amount4" />
    <result column="amount5" jdbcType="DECIMAL" property="amount5" />
    <result column="amount6" jdbcType="DECIMAL" property="amount6" />
    <result column="amount7" jdbcType="DECIMAL" property="amount7" />
    <result column="amount8" jdbcType="DECIMAL" property="amount8" />
    <result column="amount9" jdbcType="DECIMAL" property="amount9" />
    <result column="amount10" jdbcType="DECIMAL" property="amount10" />
    <result column="amount11" jdbcType="DECIMAL" property="amount11" />
    <result column="less10d" jdbcType="DECIMAL" property="less10d" />
    <result column="between10d" jdbcType="DECIMAL" property="between10d" />
    <result column="between20d" jdbcType="DECIMAL" property="between20d" />
    <result column="between30d" jdbcType="DECIMAL" property="between30d" />
    <result column="between40d" jdbcType="DECIMAL" property="between40d" />
    <result column="between50d" jdbcType="DECIMAL" property="between50d" />
    <result column="between60d" jdbcType="DECIMAL" property="between60d" />
    <result column="between70d" jdbcType="DECIMAL" property="between70d" />
    <result column="between80d" jdbcType="DECIMAL" property="between80d" />
    <result column="equal90d" jdbcType="DECIMAL" property="equal90d" />
    <result column="moret90d" jdbcType="DECIMAL" property="moret90d" />
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="AgingTableResultMap" type="xx.xx.xx.model.dto.AgingTableInfo">
    <result column="update_time" jdbcType="TIMESTAMP" property="updateTime" />
    <result column="agent_code" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="agentCode" />
    <result column="apply_name" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="name" />
    <result column="apply_id_card" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="ic" />
    <result column="finance_amount" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="financeAmount" />
    <result column="brand" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="brand" />
    <result column="model" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="model" />
    <result column="status" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="status" />
    <result column="aging" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="agingDays" />
</resultMap>



<select id="agingMerchantList" resultMap="AgingMerchantInfo">
    SELECT agent_code,branch_name FROM db_smilx.smilx_merchant_branch order by agent_code
</select>

<select id="getAging2ChartResult" resultMap="Aging2ResultMap">
    SELECT 
    <if test="counter == 'amount'">
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) BETWEEN 0 AND 9 THEN o.finance_amount ELSE 0 END) as amount1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) BETWEEN 10 AND 19 THEN o.finance_amount ELSE 0 END) as amount2,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) BETWEEN 20 AND 29 THEN o.finance_amount ELSE 0 END) as amount3,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN o.finance_amount ELSE 0 END) as amount4,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN o.finance_amount ELSE 0 END) as amount5,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) BETWEEN 50 AND 59 THEN o.finance_amount ELSE 0 END) as amount6,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) BETWEEN 60 AND 69 THEN o.finance_amount ELSE 0 END) as amount7,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) BETWEEN 70 AND 79 THEN o.finance_amount ELSE 0 END) as amount8,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) BETWEEN 80 AND 89 THEN o.finance_amount ELSE 0 END) as amount9,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) = 90 THEN o.finance_amount ELSE 0 END) as amount10,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) > 90 THEN o.finance_amount ELSE 0 END) as amount11
    </if>
    <if test="counter == 'cases'">
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) BETWEEN 0 AND 9 then DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) BETWEEN 0 AND 9 else 0 end) as less10d,
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) BETWEEN 10 AND 19 then DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) BETWEEN 10 AND 19 else 0 end) as between10d,
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) BETWEEN 20 AND 29 then DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) BETWEEN 20 AND 29 else 0 end) as between20d,
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 then DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 else 0 end) as between30d,
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) BETWEEN 40 AND 49 then DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) BETWEEN 40 AND 49 else 0 end) as between40d,
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) BETWEEN 50 AND 59 then DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) BETWEEN 50 AND 59 else 0 end) as between50d,
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) BETWEEN 60 AND 69 then DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) BETWEEN 60 AND 69 else 0 end) as between60d,
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) BETWEEN 70 AND 79 then DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) BETWEEN 70 AND 79 else 0 end) as between70d,
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) BETWEEN 80 AND 89 then DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) BETWEEN 80 AND 89 else 0 end) as between80d,
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) = 90 then DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) = 90 else 0 end) as equal90d,
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) > 90 then DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,o.update_time) >= 91 else 0 end) as moret90d
    </if>
    FROM product_info i right join smilx_brand_model m on i.prod_code = m.code 
    right join smilx_order o on m.brand = o.brand and m.model = o.model
    join db_smilx.smilx_merchant_branch mb on o.shop_no = mb.agent_code
    where 1=1
    <if test="status == 'all'">
    and (o.status="TO_SIGN" or o.status = "READY FIS UPLOAD" or o.status = "FIS PROCESS FAILED" or o.status = "VEHICLE REGN INPUT" or o.status = "SUBMIT FOR SALES CLAIM" )
    </if>
    <if test="status != 'all'">
        and o.status = #{status, jdbcType = VARCHAR} 
    </if>
    <if test="merchant != 'all'">
        and mb.agent_code = #{merchant,jdbcType = VARCHAR}
    </if>
    <if test="scheme != 'all'">
         and i.prod_name = #{scheme, jdbcType = VARCHAR} 
    </if>
</select>

<select id="agingresult" resultType="double" >
    SELECT 
    <if test="counter == 'amount'">
        sum(o.finance_amount) as finance_amount, 
    </if>
    <if test="counter == 'cases'">
        count(o.status) as count,
    </if>
    DATE(o.update_time) as update_time
    FROM product_info i right join smilx_brand_model m on i.prod_code = m.code 
    right join smilx_order o on m.brand = o.brand and m.model = o.model
    join db_smilx.smilx_merchant_branch mb on o.shop_no = mb.agent_code
    where 1=1
    <if test="status == 'all'">
        and (o.status="TO_SIGN" or o.status = "READY FIS UPLOAD" or o.status = "FIS PROCESS FAILED" or o.status = "VEHICLE REGN INPUT" or o.status = "SUBMIT FOR SALES CLAIM" )
    </if>
    <if test="status != 'all'">
            and o.status = #{status, jdbcType = VARCHAR} 
    </if>
    <if test="scheme != 'all'">
            and i.prod_name = #{scheme, jdbcType = VARCHAR} 
    </if>
    <if test="type == 'total'">
        and DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 0 AND 150 
    </if>
    <if test="type == 'less10d'">
        and DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 0 AND 9   
    </if>
    <if test="type == 'between10d'">
        and DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 10 AND 19 
    </if>
    <if test="type == 'between20d'">
        and  DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 20 AND 29 
    </if>
    <if test="type == 'between30d'">
        and DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 
    </if>
    <if test="type == 'between40d'">
        and  DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 40 AND 49 
    </if>
    <if test="type == 'between50d'">
        and  DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 50 AND 59 
    </if>
    <if test="type == 'between60d'">
        and  DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 60 AND 69 
    </if>
    <if test="type == 'between70d'">
        and  DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 70 AND 79 
    </if>
    <if test="type == 'between80d'">
        and  DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 80 AND 89  
    </if>
    <if test="type == 'equal90d'">
        and  (DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) = 90 )
    </if>
    <if test="type == 'moret90d'">
        and  (DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) >= 91 ) 
    </if>
    <if test="merchant != 'all'">
        and mb.agent_code = #{merchant,jdbcType = VARCHAR}
    </if>
</select>

<select id="agingTable" resultMap="AgingTableResultMap">
    SELECT
        o.update_time,o.shop_no,o.shop_name,o.apply_name,o.apply_id_card,o.status,o.finance_amount,o.brand,o.model,o.status
        ,datediff(current_timestamp,o.update_time) as aging 
    FROM db_smilx.product_info i right join db_smilx.smilx_brand_model m on i.prod_code = m.code 
    right join db_smilx.smilx_order o on m.brand = o.brand and m.model = o.model
    join db_smilx.smilx_merchant_branch mb on o.shop_no = mb.agent_code and o.shop_name = mb.branch_name
    where 1=1
    <if test="status == 'all'">
        and (o.status="TO_SIGN" or o.status = "READY FIS UPLOAD" or o.status = "FIS PROCESS FAILED" or o.status = "VEHICLE REGN INPUT" or o.status = "SUBMIT FOR SALES CLAIM" )
    </if>
    <if test="status != 'all'">
            and o.status = #{status, jdbcType = VARCHAR} 
    </if>
    <if test="merchant != 'all'">
        and mb.agent_code = #{merchant,jdbcType = VARCHAR}
    </if>
    <if test="scheme != 'all'">
        and i.prod_name = #{scheme, jdbcType = VARCHAR} 
    </if>
    <if test="aging == 'all'">
        and DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 0 AND 100
    </if>
    <if test="aging == 'l10d'">
        and DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 0 AND 9   
    </if>
    <if test="aging == 'b10d'">
        and DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 10 AND 19 
    </if>
    <if test="aging == 'b20d'">
        and  DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 20 AND 29 
    </if>
    <if test="aging == 'b30d'">
        and DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 
    </if>
    <if test="aging == 'b40d'">
        and  DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 40 AND 49 
    </if>
    <if test="aging == 'b50d'">
        and  DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 50 AND 59 
    </if>
    <if test="aging == 'b60d'">
        and  DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 60 AND 69 
    </if>
    <if test="aging == 'b70d'">
        and  DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 70 AND 79 
    </if>
    <if test="aging == 'b80d'">
        and  DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 80 AND 89  
    </if>
    <if test="aging == 'e90d'">
        and  (DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) = 90 )
    </if>
    <if test="aging == 'm90d'">
        and  (DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) >= 91 ) 
    </if>
</select>    

<select id="agingcountresult" resultType="Int">
    SELECT 

    count(*)

    FROM db_smilx.product_info i right join db_smilx.smilx_brand_model m on i.prod_code = m.code 
    right join db_smilx.smilx_order o on m.brand = o.brand and m.model = o.model
    join db_smilx.smilx_merchant_branch mb on o.shop_no = mb.agent_code and o.shop_name = mb.branch_name
    where 1=1
    <if test="status == 'all'">
        and (o.status="TO_SIGN" or o.status = "READY FIS UPLOAD" or o.status = "FIS PROCESS FAILED" or o.status = "VEHICLE REGN INPUT" or o.status = "SUBMIT FOR SALES CLAIM" )
    </if>
    <if test="status != 'all'">
            and o.status = #{status, jdbcType = VARCHAR} 
    </if>
    <if test="merchant != 'all'">
        and mb.agent_code = #{merchant,jdbcType = VARCHAR}
    </if>
    <if test="scheme != 'all'">
        and i.prod_name = #{scheme, jdbcType = VARCHAR} 
    </if>
    <if test="type == 'total'">
        and DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 0 AND 100
    </if>
    <if test="type == 'l10d'">
        and DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 0 AND 9   
    </if>
    <if test="type == 'b10d'">
        and DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 10 AND 19 
    </if>
    <if test="type == 'b20d'">
        and  DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 20 AND 29 
    </if>
    <if test="type == 'b30d'">
        and DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 
    </if>
    <if test="type == 'b40d'">
        and  DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 40 AND 49 
    </if>
    <if test="type == 'b50d'">
        and  DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 50 AND 59 
    </if>
    <if test="type == 'b60d'">
        and  DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 60 AND 69 
    </if>
    <if test="type == 'b70d'">
        and  DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 70 AND 79 
    </if>
    <if test="type == 'b80d'">
        and  DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) BETWEEN 80 AND 89  
    </if>
    <if test="type == 'e90d'">
        and  (DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) = 90 )
    </if>
    <if test="type == 'm90d'">
        and  (DATEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , o.update_time) >= 91 ) 
    </if>
</select>
```

#Sorry for any confusion language#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no answer and I have found the way for calling the URL , I would like to share for it in here.

In Javascript for calling the jquery for returning the data from database(mysql/mybatis).

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/dashboard/lddc-aging-data',
        dateType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(form),
        error: function() {
            console.log("error");
        },
        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res);
            if ($('#counter').val() == "cases") {
                $("#lesS10d").val(res['lesS10d']  + " case(s)");
                $("#betweeN10d").val(res['betweeN10d'] + " case(s)");
                $("#betweeN20d").val(res['betweeN20d'] + " case(s)");
                $("#betweeN30d").val(res['betweeN30d'] + " case(s)");
                $("#betweeN40d").val(res['betweeN40d'] + " case(s)");
                $("#betweeN50d").val(res['betweeN50d'] + " case(s)");
                $("#betweeN60d").val(res['betweeN60d'] + " case(s)");
                $("#betweeN70d").val(res['betweeN70d'] + " case(s)");
                $("#betweeN80d").val(res['betweeN80d'] + " case(s)");
                $("#equaL90d").val(res['equaL90d'] + " case(s)");
                $("#moreT90d").val(res['moreT90d'] + " case(s)");
                $("#total").val(res['total'] + " case(s)");
                $('.result').css("display","block");
            } else {
                $("#lesS10d").val("RM " + res['lesS10d']);
                $("#betweeN10d").val("RM " + res['betweeN10d']);
                $("#betweeN20d").val("RM " + res['betweeN20d']);
                $("#betweeN30d").val("RM " + res['betweeN30d']);
                $("#betweeN40d").val("RM " + res['betweeN40d']);
                $("#betweeN50d").val("RM " + res['betweeN50d']);
                $("#betweeN60d").val("RM " + res['betweeN60d']);
                $("#betweeN70d").val("RM " + res['betweeN70d']);
                $("#betweeN80d").val("RM " + res['betweeN80d']);
                $("#equaL90d").val("RM " + res['equaL90d']);
                $("#moreT90d").val("RM " + res['moreT90d']);
                $("#total").val("RM " + res['total']);
                $('.result').css("display","block");
            }

            // Google chart
            var result = [];
            if ($('#counter').val() == "cases") {
                result.push(["Days", "Cases","link", { role: "style" }]);

            } else {
                result.push(["Days", "Amount","link", { role: "style" }]);
            }
            if (res['aging2ChartResult'].length != 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < res['aging2ChartResult'].length; i++) {

                    if ($('#counter').val() == "amount") {
                        var item = ["Less than 10 day", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['amount1'], "../../dashboard/lddc-agingtable-l10" , "lightgreen "]
                        var item1 = ["Between 10 ~ 19 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['amount2'], "../../dashboard/lddc-agingtable-b10" , "lightgreen"]
                        var item2 = ["Between 20 ~ 29 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['amount3'], "../../dashboard/lddc-agingtable-b20" , "lightgreen"]
                        var item3 = ["Between 30 ~ 39 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['amount4'], "../../dashboard/lddc-agingtable-b30" , "lightgreen"]
                        var item4 = ["Between 40 ~ 49 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['amount5'], "../../dashboard/lddc-agingtable-b40" , "lightgreen"]
                        var item5 = ["Between 50 ~ 59 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['amount6'], "../../dashboard/lddc-agingtable-b50" , "lightgreen"]
                        var item6 = ["Between 60 ~ 69 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['amount7'], "../../dashboard/lddc-agingtable-b60" , "lightgreen"]
                        var item7 = ["Between 70 ~ 79 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['amount8'], "../../dashboard/lddc-agingtable-b70" , "lightgreen"]
                        var item8 = ["Between 80 ~ 89 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['amount9'], "../../dashboard/lddc-agingtable-b80" , "lightgreen"]
                        var item9 = ["At 90 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['amount10'], "../../dashboard/lddc-agingtable-e90" , "lightgreen"]
                        var item10 = ["More than 90 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['amount11'], "../../dashboard/lddc-agingtable-m90" , "lightgreen"]
                            // console.log(res);
                    } else {
                        var item = ["Less than 10 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['less10d'], "../../dashboard/lddc-agingtable-l10" , "lightgreen"]
                        var item1 = ["Between 10 ~ 19 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['between10d'], "../../dashboard/lddc-agingtable-b10" , "lightgreen"]
                        var item2 = ["Between 20 ~ 29 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['between20d'], "../../dashboard/lddc-agingtable-b20" , "lightgreen"]
                        var item3 = ["Between 30 ~ 39 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['between30d'], "../../dashboard/lddc-agingtable-b30" , "lightgreen"]
                        var item4 = ["Between 40 ~ 49 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['between40d'], "../../dashboard/lddc-agingtable-b40" , "lightgreen"]
                        var item5 = ["Between 50 ~ 59 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['between50d'], "../../dashboard/lddc-agingtable-b50" , "lightgreen"]
                        var item6 = ["Between 60 ~ 69 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['between60d'], "../../dashboard/lddc-agingtable-b60" , "lightgreen"]
                        var item7 = ["Between 70 ~ 79 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['between70d'], "../../dashboard/lddc-agingtable-b70" , "lightgreen"]
                        var item8 = ["Between 80 ~ 89 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['between80d'], "../../dashboard/lddc-agingtable-b80" , "lightgreen"]
                        var item9 = ["At 90 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['equal90d'], "../../dashboard/lddc-agingtable-e90" , "lightgreen"]
                        var item10 = ["More than 90 Days", res['aging2ChartResult'][i]['moret90d'], "../../dashboard/lddc-agingtable-m90" , "lightgreen"]

                    }

                    result.push(item, item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, item10);
                }
                google.charts.load("current", {
                    packages: ['corechart']
                });
                google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

                function drawChart() {
                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(result);
                    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
                    view.setColumns([0, 1, {
                            calc: "stringify",
                            sourceColumn: 1,
                            type: "string",
                            role: "annotation"
                        },
                        3
                    ]);

                    var options = {
                        title: $('#counter').val() == "amount" ? "Amount(RM)" : "Cases",
                        vAxis: {
                            title: form.unit == "amount" ? "Amount(RM)" : "Cases",
                        },
                        hAxis: {
                            title: 'Aging Days'
                        },
                        width: 1100,
                        height: 400,
                        bar: {
                            groupWidth: "75%"
                        },
                        legend: {
                            position: "none"
                        },
                    };
                    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
                    chart.draw(view, options);

                    // trying
                    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
                    function selectHandler(e) {
                          var selection = chart.getSelection();
                          if (selection.length == true && selection[0].row != null) {
                            console.log(selection[0]);
                            console.log(data.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0]['row'], 2 ));
                            window.location = data.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0]['row'], 2 );
                               
                                
                           } 
                        }

                    //trying

                }
                $('.chart').show();
            } else {
                $('.chart').hide();
            }
            
        },
    });
```

You need to add the URL in the **controller** for calling the url and display it in the table. Do not forget to add new interface for **DAO,DTO,SERVICE** and **Mapper** for the getting the data. Last but not least, create new html for the link calling when you click the bar chart as above showed.